# Facebook Graph API - Sync response from batch request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to perform a Facebook Graph API batch request to post messages or links to a given Facebook page as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Batch call example (post 2 messages to same Facebook page):

```
access_token=...&batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"000000000000000/feed?fields=created_time,id,permalink_url","body":"message=page+test+post+4"},{"method":"POST","relative_url":"000000000000000/feed?fields=created_time,id,permalink_url","body":"message=Test2+status+update"}]&include_headers=false
```

Response snippet for above request:

```
[{
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{\"created_time\":\"2017-06-30T01:00:02+0000\",\"id\":\"000000000000000_157349X08600319X\",\"permalink_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/permalink.php?story_fbid=157349X09600319X&id=000000000000000\"}"
},
{
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{\"created_time\":\"2017-06-30T01:00:02+0000\",\"id\":\"000000000000000_157349X08600319X\",\"permalink_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/permalink.php?story_fbid=157349X08600319X&id=000000000000000\"}"
}]
```

The trouble I'm having is trying to map or sync the responses to the parent requests in the above example.  It would be nice if the Graph API allowed some arbitrary ID for each request in the batch to be sent and then returned with the corresponding response so I could then use it for mapping purposes, but it doesn't or at least doesn't document it.  For my app, I need to sync up the responses to save the permalinks to the database for each parent request.

I realize I can request additional fields to return other than just the id, permalink, etc. But, none of the available fields gives me what I need for mapping.  The 'message' field might do the trick, but that doesn't seem like the right approach.

My other option is to perform single requests, but I like the notion of batch requests and the savings it brings in reducing the number of server calls.

Comment: I don’t really see what the problem is. You get the responses in the same order as the individual requests in the batch - so all you have to do is remember on your end, what data you send in what order in the first place ...

Comment: @CBroe The Facebook document states that for batch operations the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Only the order of _execution_ is not guaranteed. But the order of the responses will correspond to the order of your original requests, quote: _“The ordering of responses correspond with the ordering of operations in the request, so developers should process responses accordingly to determine which operations were successful and which should be retried in a subsequent operation.”_

Comment: @CBroe Ah I see the quote, thanks for pointing that out.  Will confirm and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only the order of execution is not guaranteed. But the order of the responses will correspond to the order of your original requests, quote: “The ordering of responses correspond with the ordering of operations in the request, so developers should process responses accordingly to determine which operations were successful and which should be retried in a subsequent operation.” – CBroe

If anyone views this issue, answer from CBroe is correct -- Initial testing confirms Facebook batch responses are returned in the same order of requests sent in the batch.